# What is "2LUN" mode in connection with RAID?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, terminology

I've came across RAID products that also list [JBOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBOD#JBOD) (just a bunch of disks) mode and *2LUN mode*. What the heck is 2LUN mode?

I could not find a description; the closest thing seems to be [LUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Unit_Number) 'logical unit number' but I don't get the 2LUN thing.

---

**UPDATE 1**

This is what Wikipedia has to say about JBOD:

> JBOD (derived from "just a bunch of disks"): an architecture involving
>   multiple hard drives, while making them accessible **either as
>   independent hard drives, or as a combined (spanned) single logical
>   volume** with no actual RAID functionality.

So JBOD can actually mean **two** different (albeit related) things.

[Answer](https://superuser.com/a/764035/129520) of [Guest](https://superuser.com/users/329696/guest) says 2LUN means *no spanning*.

Does this *suggest* that 2LUN would simply mean the JBOD-variant with *no span*?

Answer (score 0):

2LUN means that each disk is seen as an independent unit. No spanning.

Comment: so it simply means the JBOD variant when they are independent?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question, but here's the answer, anyway:

- **2LUN** is a mode when your drives are visible as *separate, independent devices*, e.g., `D:` and `E:` (Windows) or `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` (Linux);
- **JBOD** is a mode when your disks are represented as a *single* device (`D:` or `/dev/sdb`, correspondingly), but your *data* is stored sequentially, which usually means that the second device is even accessed only after the first device is filled up;
- **RAID-0** is also represented as a single device (`D:` or `/dev/sdb`) but, differently to **JBOD**, it assumes that a reasonably large file would be stored roughly on each drive (e.g., 50% on each disk in a 2-disk configuration, or 33% in 3-disk configuration, etc).